# Use Context to update data on every screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my first time working with context. So, I've about 6 screens and on each screen, the user selects some options and on the 6th screen, I want all the information that they have selected/entered on previous screens.

I've created a class called `context.js` in which I've done this:

```
export const bookData = React.createContext({
    bookingData: {
        "app_date": 0,
        "app_est": "",
        "app_phone": "",
        "app_ic": "",
        "app_timeslots": {},
        "app_hour": 0,
        "app_est_url": "",
        "app_year": 0,
        "app_email": "",
    }
})
```

This is the payload I'll need on the 6th screen. Now on-screen 1 I've imported it as `import BookContext from '../utils/context'` and this screen has a next button in which I want to pass data to `app_email`, `app_phone`, and `app_ic` which I've in variables that I populated using. `useState()` on this screen:

```
<MainActionButton title={'Next'} pressEvent={() => { 
alert(email + phone + ic)
}}  />
```

Here `email`, `phone`, and `ic` are set using a `useState()`. So how do I use `BookContext` that I've imported inside the `pressEvent` to access/update the context?

I might be completely off track here as I don't fully understand the concept of context yet so a brief answer will be appericiated.

Answer (score 1):

For updating the value of the context you can follow this simple pattern:

1. Maintain a state in the component that has the provider. For example, you can have something like this:

   ```
   const initialState = {
   bookingData: {
       "app_date": 0,
       "app_est": "",
       "app_phone": "",
       "app_ic": "",
       "app_timeslots": {},
       "app_hour": 0,
       "app_est_url": "",
       "app_year": 0,
       "app_email": "",
      }
   };

   const [bookData, setBookData] = react.useState(initialState);
   ```
2. Pass the `bookData` and `setBookData` as context's value:

   ```
   <BookData.Provider value={{state: bookData, updateState: setBookData}}></BookData.Provider>
   ```
3. Now in the child components you can use the passed object(value) for accessing and updating the state.

   ```
   const { state, updateState } = React.useContext(BookData)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you would need to create an "api" inside your context to update records (e.g. `bookContext.update(payload)`), for example:

```
import * as React from "react";

let ContextOne = React.createContext();

let initialState = {
  count: 10,
  currentColor: "#bada55"
};

let reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "reset":
      return initialState;
    case "increment":
      return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
    case "decrement":
      return { ...state, count: state.count - 1 };
    case "set-color":
      return { ...state, currentColor: action.payload };
  }
};

function ContextOneProvider(props) {
  let [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  let value = { state, dispatch };

  return (
    <ContextOne.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</ContextOne.Provider>
  );
}

let ContextOneConsumer = ContextOne.Consumer;

export { ContextOne, ContextOneProvider, ContextOneConsumer };
```

i wrap my app in my custom context/provider:

```
import { ContextOneProvider } from "./ContextOne";
import { App } from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <ContextOneProvider>
    <App />
  </ContextOneProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

now when I consume `ContextOne`:

```
function App() {
  let { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(ContextOne);
  // dispatch will update the context and re-render
}
```

I wrote a walkthrough about that in:
https://dev.to/oieduardorabelo/react-hooks-how-to-create-and-update-contextprovider-1f68

One library that I recommend to abstract React.Context is:

- https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated-next